# Initilize a view with a ViewPager using a FragmentPagerAdpater with a FragmentAcivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I am using a ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdapter inside a FragmentActivity (say that five times fast - I dare you :)

Anyways, I have things displaying correctly but I need to be able to intialise my views. Before fragments, its easy: Assign an id to the view, then use FindViewById - but FragmentPagerAdapter loads view lazily (as it should).

My Question: How can I access those view to initialise them.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I access those view to initialise them.

Use `findViewById()` in `onCreateView()`, `onActivityCreated()`, etc. of your fragment.

Comment: I guessed this, but I am building a library, and if this is the case, then I must make an interface as people who are using the library will not have access to my FragmentPagerAdapter (and Fragments). I thought that using FragmentAcivity, I could override a method instead whereby this would be possible? Are you sure this can't be done (although I can't find such a method)

Comment: @BarrySteyn: You needed the interface anyway, as the users of your library would not have access to your widgets, or your activity, or anything else inside your library not exposed by said interface.

Comment: something is very wrong. When I create the interface, and I pass the newly created (I have stepped through this via the debugger, so I can see it has been created correctly), findViewById still returns null???

Comment: @BarrySteyn: We do not have enough information to really provide much assistance.

Comment: Hi - I have added your result as correct @CommonsWare. I am quite new to fragments (Actually, I am just shy of two weeks into learning Android itself). What I needed was to run the findViewById on the view object itself. That solved my problem.

Comment: @BarrySteyn: Ah, yes. When working with fragments, you call `findViewById()` on whatever you created in `onCreateView()` to find the widgets inside of there.